# How can I get all the info of a Webhook of a channel in Python's discord library?

Tags: discord.py

How can I get all the info of a Webhook of a channel?

I've found [the API reference of the discord library](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). But I'm stuck at the beginning and don't see how I can even start. Could I get some help finding a way to get started?

Comment: Asking a question without any code snippets and without showing what you have tried so far is not a good question. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So I have to assume that you have trouble getting started and can't see the right place in the API reference. I tried to formulate the question in that direction. Feel free to edit your question again if this is not the main problem. But then you should also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I checked like you said the API reference but I only found how to create a webhook and not how to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you wanted.

But lets say there is a webhook in channel 'a'. We can use the following code. To retrieve all the webhooks linked to that particular channel (when this command is called in channel 'a'):

```
@commands.command()
async def get_channel_webhooks(self, ctx):

    # Loops through every webhook linked to the channel
    for hook in await ctx.channel.webhooks():
        hook_channel_id = hook.channel_id
        await ctx.send(f"channel_id of hook: {hook_channel_id}")
```

When you read this [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook#webhook-support) you will see what you can do with the webhook object. In the code previously shown. We used `hook.channel_id` to retrieve the channel_id the webhook is linked to. And `ctx.channel.webhooks()` to retrieve a full list of all webhooks linked to that channel ([documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20webhook#discord.TextChannel.webhooks)).

But you can also get information about: user, url, name etc (read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook#webhook-support) for more),